# Bluetooth Transferring Strings incorrectly

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So I'm making an app that has to send an `Arraylist<String>` over a Bluetooth connection. The `ArrayList<String>` could be hundreds of lines long. I'm just testing it right now with several lines of data. When I transfer data to the other phone, it immediately prints it out to the logcat. It transfers a portion of the start of the line, but then sends a whole bunch of these question marks. When I play around with the `byte[] buffer` size, lowering it seems to get rid of a lot of question marks but the lines aren't preserved, raising it seems to send more question marks. Anyways - Take a look at the console output:
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzN6Y.png)

Sending code:

```
public void run() {
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); // discovery is heavy on the Bluetooth bandwith

        try { 
            socket.connect();

            // Decompile the enter file system of this event into one giant arraylist<string>
            EventDecompiler decompiler = new EventDecompiler(getApplicationContext());
            ArrayList<String> lines = decompiler.decompile(eventName, false);  

            ConnectedThread thread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
            thread.start();

            // First, let the other device know how much information we're sending
            thread.write(String.valueOf(lines.size()).getBytes());

            for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                thread.write(lines.get(i).getBytes());
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            cancel();
            return;
        }
    }
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            outStream.write(bytes);
        } catch(IOException e) {}
    }
```

Here's the receiving code:

```
    public void run() {
            byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    buffer = new byte[1024];

                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = inStream.read(buffer);
                    status.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            status.setText("Receiving "+progress+ " / "+total);
                        }
                    });
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
 private static Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
        case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
            String string = new String(readBuf);
            received.add(string);
            if(progress < 1) {
                total = 100;
            }
            progress++;
            if(progress == 15) {
                for(int i = 0; i < received.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(received.get(i));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Any ideas of how to dynamically scale the buffer size or something else that's going wrong?

Comment: You are sending int bytes to the handler. But the handler does not look at the value and adds the whole readBuf.

Comment: You better add a buffered input reader so you can read lines. You should send lines too by adding "\n" at the end of every string.

Comment: could you give me a code example of how to do this? @greenapps

Comment: The things you want are all standard. Google for them. Look for server client examples too.

Comment: Ok thanks - I'll give it a shot